# How to import data from a csv file into database using prisma

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I'm using Prisma and trying to seed my database with the following command:

```js
const accountSeedFile = join(process.cwd(), './prisma/seeds/accounts.csv');

const accountSeedPromise = prisma.$executeRaw`
  COPY "accounts"(id, name, bank)
  FROM ${accountSeedFile}
  DELIMITER ','
  CSV HEADER;
`;

const [accountsResult] = await Promise.all([accountSeedPromise]);
```

But every time I execute `prisma db seed` I get a error:

```bash
code: 'P2010',
clientVersion: '4.6.1',
meta: {
  code: '42601',
  message: 'db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"'
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Btw I'm following the docs here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw

Expecting to work properly and seed my database

Comment: Hello, PostgreSQL has `RAISE NOTICE` functionality. You may print your query string and see if it has a flaw.

Comment: I do not anyway know what `prisma` is, but you may try to divide your query into strings that have newlines. Maybe  you can get a line number of an error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Prisma is like a ORM, so I dont think my query is not even hitting the postgres

Comment: Yep. There is an upvote if it turns out to be useful ;)

Comment: The "ORM" does not tell anything to me. But the error is plain tell you that you have a syntax flaw in your query. IMHO.

Comment: I'm going to say it is this, `... FROM ${accountSeedFile} ...` where `${accountSeedFile}` is being taken as a parameter(`$1`).  From here [Considerations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#considerations) template variables can only be used for data values. You will need to see the examples at the link to see how to do the proper string interpolation.